# Wait for Coroutine completion inside onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, coroutinescope

I'm executing a coroutine inside `onCreate` to do an API call.
I would like to wait the api response before execution of `onCreateView` because I'm using the answer to display information.

Usually, Im' using this to wait for a job

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
     job!!.join()
     //call to next method
}
```

But I can't call `onCreateView` by myself. It is called in lifecycle process of my fragment.
So using this, I got `NullPointerException` because I didn't already get the answer from my API.

I also though to use `runBlocking`. But it's freeze UI and I'm using a loader animation during API call

For now, I'm using this abberration :

```
while(!jobGet!!.isCompleted) {}
```

It work's but I can't leave that....

this is my code :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

     val bundle = this.arguments
     if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("eventSuggestionDto")) {
          val eventSuggestionDto = bundle.getSerializable("eventSuggestionDto") as EventSuggestionDto
          (activity as MainActivity).startAnim()
          jobGet = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
              getEvent(eventSuggestionDto.objectId)
          }
          while(!jobGet!!.isCompleted) {}
          (activity as MainActivity).stopAnim()
            
     }
}
```

So how to replace `while(!jobGet!!.isCompleted) {}`?

Comment: One way or another, the UI is going to have to wait for this long-running code before it can display the data. If you wait on the main thread, you have a frozen UI, which is janky and risks an ANR error. Either your Fragment should start by showing a blank UI at first and then filling in the data when ready, or you should start fetching the data before you start the Fragment and only start showing it when the data has already been acquired, but then the previous fragment needs to disable buttons, etc until the transaction occurs.

Comment: You are right @Tenfour04. I changed the way to get my data. I first display blank UI (with loading animation), I make the API call, then I wait the API answer to update my UI and stop the loading animation. Thanks ! :)